# DOM on div with auto width

Tags: javascript, html, css, dom

Assuming I created a div named .main-nav

And I styled the section header like this:

```
.main-nav{
    width: auto;
}
```

Within the div there's another div named #navbar-brand​

```
#navbar-brand​{
    padding:15;
}​​
```

​If I want to do a DOM which when the main-nav's width is longer than 768px then padding of #navbar-brand is gone, how should it be done???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be done with javascript of course but more efficiently with pure css [media queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries) when the viewport size is over 768px. Be aware that the media query approach assumes that the .main-nav width is 100% of the viewport width, if the parent container of .main-nav is smaller than the viewport this approach won't necessarily work as you expected

Insert this to your css-file after your default #navbar-brand-settings

```
@media screen and (min-width: 768px) {
 #navbar-brand​{
     padding: 0;
 }​​
}
```

Also you will need to add meta viewport -tag to your page for it to work properly with the viewport size, read more [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Mozilla/Mobile/Viewport_meta_tag).

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this using media CSS query as shown below:

```
@media screen and (min-width: 768px) {
    #navbar-brand {
        padding: 0;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this, But always create a fiddle of what you have done with your codes or post your entire codes over-here.

CSS

```
    .main-nav{
      width:auto;
      background:#111;
    }

#navbar-brand{
    padding:15px;
    background:#f22;
}
```

JS

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(window).resize(function(){
    var wdth = $(".main-nav").width();
  if(wdth >= "768"){
    $("#navbar-brand").css('padding','0');
  }
  else{
    $("#navbar-brand").css('padding','15px');
  }
});
});
```

Answer (score 0):

**.main-nav** is a block element and thus occupy full width across the screen.
Adding *width : auto* probably does nothing there.

Its child **#navbar-brand** is also a block element which has a padding of 15 **(you forgot unit there)**.

You want to do a DOM **(It's vague , make the statement more clear !)**

But if trying to do DOM manipulation using js ,

1. you have to attach processing stuff to events like resize (which probably most mobile browsers don't have)
2. Or use *setInterval* to check it and cancel it when done  Or simply call a function to
   check when DOM is ready or page is loaded

Or

**SUPER SIMPLE WAY**

3. If you are just altering css properties then use media queries (see **MDN**).